# ggplot2 image with too big legend when converted to jpg format

Tags: r, plot

I am making a plot to be submitted to an academic journal.
I used png() function for anti-aliasing, but the legend in the plot is too big.

Please refer to the sample code and plot below.

```
posn.d <- position_dodge(0.1)
plot_test <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(gear), hp, shape = factor(am)))+
  ylab("HP")+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", position = posn.d, aes(shape = factor(am)), size = 1)+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", position = posn.d, aes(group = factor(am), linetype = factor(am)), size = 0.4)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, fun.args = list(mult = 1), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1, position =posn.d, size=0.3)+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = "white"), panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=1,face="bold",size=6), axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=6, face = "bold"), axis.text.y=element_text(size=6, face = "bold"),
        axis.line.x=element_line(size=0.2),axis.line.y=element_line(size=0.2),axis.ticks=element_line(size=0.2),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=0,vjust=2,face="bold", size=3))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "AM", labels = c("am0", "am1"), values = c("solid", "dotted"))+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "AM", labels = c("am0", "am1"), values = c(16, 15))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("three", "four", "five"))


png(width = 100, height = 35, units="mm", filename = "test.jpg", type = "cairo", antialias = "subpixel", family = "malgun", res = 300)
plot_test
dev.off()
```

[image]

I tried to reduce the size of the legend title and text, by adding

```
legend.title = element_text(size = 4, face = "bold"), legend.text = element_text(size = 4)
```

in the theme().
But the space between legend texts and title are still too large and look difficult to control.

Could anyone help me without changing the whole image size or resolution?
(Because the size and resolution can not be controlled freely to conform to the guidelines of the journal.)

Comment: FYI - giving it a .jpg extension within the `png` call doesn't make the resulting image format jpeg (which would be inappropriate for this type of graphic anyway). The result is still a png file.

Comment: I didn't know that. Actually I don't know much about the details of image format. The image was saved as *.jpg anyway. Thanks for the info. :)